# axiom 5 of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the set of all ordered pairs of real numbers $(u_1,u_2)$ with $u_2 >0$. Consider the following addition and scalar multiplication operations on **u** $= (u_1,u_2)$ and **v** $= (v_1,v_2)$

**u** + **v** = $(u_1+v_1+1,5u_2 v_2)$ , $k$**u** = $(ku_1,ku_2)$

1. Compute **u** $+$ **v** for **u** $= (-7, 4)$ and **v** $= (-4, 7)$.

Answer: $-10,140$

2. If the set $V$ satisfies Axiom 4 of a vector space (the existence of a zero vector), what would be the zero vector?

Answer: $-1,1/5$

3. If **u** $= (1, 9)$, what would be the negative of the vector u referred to in Axiom 5 of a vector space?

I know 1 and 2 I did correctly. But am having difficulty with number 3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The negative of a vector $u$ is defined as the vector $v$ such that $u  + v = v+ u = 0$, your zero vector.

So to find this solve $(1,9) + (v_1,v_2) = (-1, 1/5)$ using the addition defined above.

Comment: So as an example u = (-1,5), v = (1,-5)? (-1,5) + (1,-5) =  (1,-5)+(-1,5) = 0

Comment: $(-1,5) + (1,-5) = (-1+1+1, 5(-5)(5) ) = (1, -125)$, this is not $(-1,1/5)$, you want something that adds to get $(-1, 1/5)$. For your example if you keep $u = (-1,5)$ then your $v$ would be the vector $v = (-1, 1/(125))$

Comment: Ah ah ah, so the correct answer to my problem is (-1,1/225)

Comment: sorry typo (-2,1/225)

Comment: I believe $v_1 = -3$. The first component is $1+ v_1 +1 = -1 \Rightarrow v_1 = -3$

Answer (score 1):

if $v = \mathbf 0$

$u+v = u\\
(u_1 + v_1 + 1, 5u_2v_2) = (u_1,u_2)\\
u_1+ v_1 + 1 =u_1\\
v_1 = -1\\
5u_2v_2 = u_2\\
v_2 = \frac 15\\
(-1,\frac 15) = \mathbf 0$

if $v = -u$ then $u+v = \mathbf 0$

$u + v = (-1,\frac 15)\\
u_1 + v_1 + 1 = -1\\
v_1 = -2 - u_1\\
5u_2v_2 = \frac 15\\
v_2 = \frac {1}{25u_2}\\
u = (1,9)\\
-u = (-3, \frac{1}{25\cdot 9})$